# $A.util.removeClass happens seconds after execution

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, lightning-renderer

I'm changing data in a component and show a spinner as soon as changes happen.

The handler executes all the lines, but `$A.util.removeClass(cmp.find("loading"), 'slds-hide');` seems to be fired after the reload is done. This is not what I expect, since my execution order is:

- show spinner
- update table data
- hide spinner

Controller:

```
dataChanged: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    $A.util.removeClass(cmp.find("spinner"), 'slds-hide');
    console.log(Date.now());

    var table = cmp.get("v.data");
    helper.updateTable(table, cmp);
    cmp.set("v.data", table);

    console.log(Date.now());
    $A.util.addClass(cmp.find("spinner"), 'slds-hide');
},
```

(when I remove the last line, the spinner shows up, so there is no typo etc.)

Result:

- log: 1507546819580
- updateTable
- reload UI
- log: 1507546821040
- start & stop spinner (the same time, so no effect)

Where does the delay come from and how can I avoid it?

*(This question is part 2 of [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/194060/cmp-set-is-blocking-the-ui-to-re-render-but-no-event-is-triggered), after some more testing I came closer to the root cause)*

Comment: did you did event.stopPropagation after handling?

Comment: @ManjotSingh no, nothing like this. As mentioned, I am able to handle the event properly.

Comment: i am saying just stop event after handling

Comment: @ManjotSingh please explain why this would help here.

Comment: Does adding `getElement()` on to the end of your `find()` improve the performance? If that is just as slow, could you try `cmp.find("spinner").getElement().classList.add('slds-hide')`. I know this is against best practice as per the docs, but for this use case it might be okay...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lightning has some sort of digest cycle analogous to what you see in Angular and other front-end frameworks. When you make changes that affect the UI, they are not evaluated instantly but rather as part of the framework lifecycle.

As far as I know, when you fire an event it happens asynchronously. That means the current cycle continues executing and completes, and the async event doesn't evaluate in the UI until another lifecycle. Have you tried also logging the time during the steps of the `dataChanged` function to see the real sequence?

What's probably (approximately) happening is:

- You fire the `startWaiting` event which is async
- Your helper function updates the table
- Your helper function sets the table data
- The function finishes executing
- The 1st framework lifecycle now reaches the stage where it re-renders the UI
- The UI blocks while processing the re-render of the table
- The re-render finishes and so does the 1st lifecycle
- Now there is a `startWaiting` event to handle and the 2nd lifecycle starts
- The `$A.util.removeClass` function sets the class parameter of the component
- The 2nd lifecycle now re-renders

It sounds like what you really need is to make the spinner visible before re-rendering the table can block the UI. So I would flip this around. Fire the `$A.util.removeClass` immediately, not through an event. Then **fire an event which completes the table update**. If I'm right about this, the 1st lifecycle will complete quickly and show the spinner, while the table update will run in a 2nd lifecycle.

EDIT:

---

It is possible to break out of the Lifecycle as [stated here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm)

```
dataChanged: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    $A.util.removeClass(cmp.find("spinner"), 'slds-hide');

    window.setTimeout(
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            var table = cmp.get("v.data");
            helper.updateTable(table, cmp);
            cmp.set("v.data", table);

            $A.util.addClass(cmp.find("spinner"), 'slds-hide');
        }), 0
    );
},
```

Comment: thanks for listing the execution order, the async part might clarify why all this happens. But the approach to call removeClass directly won't work since the inner component has no access to the outer components spinner element.

Comment: I also checked, if I could show a spinner in the same component, even there the same effect appears. lines are executed, but the class is not removed. I will make the question simpler with this information.

Comment: I see you've modified the code sample to no longer run the spinner as an event. You state the execution order is "show spinner, update table data, hide spinner". But that's not what Lightning does. The real execution order is "update spinner class data, update table data, update spinner class data, **render all of it**".

Comment: So what I suggest is, your `dataChanged` function should remove the class and then fire an event, and that's all. Move all the remaining lines into the event handler function. The event handler should set the data and remove the class again. Now your execution order will be "update spinner class data, **render spinner**, update table data, update spinner class data **render table and hide spinner**."

Comment: Tried this, didn't work either :(  `$A.util.removeClass(cmp.find("spinner"), 'slds-hide'); cmp.getEvent("dataChangeInternal").fire();` Seems like it's not really async but kind of fixed in the lifecycle.

Comment: Humm... although this is not a highly recommended course of action, for argument's sake, what are your results when you do: `window.setTimeout(
    $A.getCallback(function() {
        // inside here, populate the table and then re-add the slds-hide class
    }), 500
);`

Comment: Booom!! that did the trick! I mean it's hacky, but for now it will be my solution :) I actually played around with async stuff at the beginning, but back than I wasn't really aware where the problem was located. Can you edit your Answer, so I can give you the bounty? btw I set the timeout to 0ms. $A.getCallback seems to be unnecessary.
You might also add [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm) that is highly related to this, I guess thats where you got the inspiration from :)

Comment: I added it myself because the bounty will go away in 12 hours, thank you for investigating and helping me!

Comment: Interesting that $A.getCallback seems unnecessary. In general if it's not used it might go and change the data outside the rendering lifecycle. But Lightning does work in mysterious ways. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem when trying to use a spinner to save a record. Going off the docs:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_lifecycle.htm

> A component is instantiated, rendered, and rerendered during its
>   lifecycle. A component is rerendered only when there’s a programmatic
>   or value change that would require a rerender, such as when a browser
>   event triggers an action that updates its data.

**Simply force a rerender after each remove/add class** by updating the value of an attribute displayed in the view. E.g. A string that says "Spinner is spinning now..." when active.

```
dataChanged: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    $A.util.removeClass(cmp.find("spinner"), 'slds-hide');
    cmp.set("v.spinnerDescription", "Spinner is spinning now...");

    var table = cmp.get("v.data");
    helper.updateTable(table, cmp);
    cmp.set("v.data", table);

    $A.util.addClass(cmp.find("spinner"), 'slds-hide');
    cmp.set("v.spinnerDescription", "Spinner is resting.");
},
```

Comment: Didn't work for me :(

Comment: Didn't work for me either